# How to compare strings using (<,>)

Tags: c++, compare, quicksort

I am trying to compare two strings for my while loop, heres a snippet of my code:

```
//variables
string pivot, array[10];
int rightBoundary;

//loop
while( pivot < array[rightBoundary])
```

this code is from a tutorial on quick sort but im trying to convert it to work with strings.

so my question is what is the best way to do this comparison.

currently I get this error (Unhandled exception at 0x774215de in quickSortNumbers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x965b7214.)

and help will be great thanks :)

edit: sorry should have just uploaded all my code, i think the problem may actually be the string array. heres all my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define array1_SIZE 5                //change the array1 size here

void Printarray1(string* array1, int n);
void QuickSort(string* array1, int startIndex, int endIndex);
int Splitarray1(string* array1, string pivot, int startIndex, int endIndex);
void swap(string &a, string &b);

int main(void)
{
    string array1[array1_SIZE];
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < array1_SIZE; i++)               //array1 elements input
    {
        cout<<"Enter an integer : ";
        cin>>array1[i];
    }

    cout<<endl<<"The list you input is : "<<endl;
    Printarray1(array1, array1_SIZE);
    QuickSort(array1,0,array1_SIZE - 1);    //sort array1 from first to last element
    cout<<endl<<"The list has been sorted, now it is : "<<endl;
    Printarray1(array1, array1_SIZE);

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    int read;
    cin >> read;
    return 0;
}

/* This function swaps two numbers
  Arguments :
           a, b - the numbers to be swapped
  */
void swap(string &a, string &b)
{
    string temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

/* This function prints an array1.
  Arguments :
           array1 - the array1 to be printed
           n - number of elements in the array1
  */
void Printarray1(string* array1, int n)
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {   
        cout << array1[i] << '\t';
    }
}

/* This function does the quicksort
  Arguments :
           array1 - the array1 to be sorted
           startIndex - index of the first element of the section
           endIndex - index of the last element of the section
  */
void QuickSort(string* array1, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    string pivot = array1[startIndex];  //pivot element is  the leftmost element
    int splitPoint;

    if(endIndex > startIndex)       //if they are equal, it means there is
        //only one element and quicksort's job
        //here is finished
    {
        splitPoint = Splitarray1(array1, pivot, startIndex, endIndex);
        //Splitarray1() returns the position where
        //pivot belongs to
        array1[splitPoint] = pivot;
        QuickSort(array1, startIndex, splitPoint-1);   //Quick sort first half
        QuickSort(array1, splitPoint+1, endIndex);   //Quick sort second half
    }
}

/* This function splits the array1 around the pivot
  Arguments :
           array1 - the array1 to be split
           pivot - pivot element whose position will be returned
           startIndex - index of the first element of the section
           endIndex - index of the last element of the section
  Returns :
         the position of the pivot
  */
int Splitarray1(string* array1, string pivot, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int leftBoundary = startIndex;
    int rightBoundary = endIndex;

    while(leftBoundary < rightBoundary) //shuttle pivot until the     boundaries meet
    {
        while( pivot < array1[rightBoundary]//keep moving until a lesser element is found
               && rightBoundary > leftBoundary)   //or until the  leftBoundary is reached
        {
            rightBoundary--;                        //move left
        }
        swap(array1[leftBoundary], array1[rightBoundary]);
        //Printarray1(array1, array1_SIZE);          //Uncomment this line for study

        while( pivot >= array1[leftBoundary]          //keep moving until a greater or equal element is found
               && leftBoundary < rightBoundary)   //or until the rightBoundary is reached
        {
            leftBoundary++;                      //move right
        }
        swap(array1[rightBoundary], array1[leftBoundary]);
        //Printarray1(array1, array1_SIZE);          //Uncomment this line for study
    }
    return leftBoundary;                              //leftBoundary is the split point because
    //the above while loop exits only when 
    //leftBoundary and rightBoundary are equal
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `rightBoundary` just before the crash?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an out-of-bounds error, possibly due to not initializing `rightBoundary`. Strings can be compared perfectly fine with the comparison operators.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <string>
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s1 = "hello";
    string s2 = "world!";

    string lower = s1 < s2 ? s1 : s2;

    cout << lower; //prints "hello"
}
```

To compare without worrying about case, you can use `lexicographical_compare` with your own comparer function:

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::lexicographical_compare;

#include <cctype>
using std::tolower;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <string>
using std::string;

bool nocase_compare (char one, char two)
{
    return tolower (one) < tolower (two);
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = "Hello";
    string s2 = "happy";

    if (lexicographical_compare (s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), nocase_compare))
        cout << s1;
    else
        cout << s2;
    //prints "happy" even though 'H' < 'h'
}
```

If you really want to use < and >, you'll have to make a small wrapper for `string` that implements your versions of `operator<` and `operator>`. The ones implemented in `string` use the default `lexicographical_compare`.

Comment: hi i did initialize that variable sorry i didnt show it, please look at my entire code to see if you can spot the error, you can complile the code to see where it crashes.

Comment: well i am using visual studio with it all built in but i cannot see where the problem is :S

Comment: well this is the line that it will crash on :
    splitPoint = Splitarray1(array1, pivot, startIndex, endIndex);
also do you know a better way to compare strings as "hello" and "Hello" will be sorted differently and i want this sorting alphbeticly?

Comment: I updated my answer to not take case into account. Step into `Splitarray1` and walk through it because it sure isn't crashing on that line itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using < for comparing strings is fine, but might not be what you expect if you want alphabetical order since all lowercase letters come before uppercase letters if you want lexicographical ordering you should use lexicographical_compare instead.

The reason your code crashes is because you do not assign any initial value to rightBoundary, you should do:

```
int rightBoundary = 0;
```

Since otherwise rightBoundary will have an arbitrary initial value which will with overwhelming probability be greater than the size of 'array' and cause out-of-bounds access.

Comment: hi i did initialize that variable sorry i didnt show it, please look at my entire code to see if you can spot the error, you can complile the code to see where it crashes.